# axvline with pandas bar plot using periods

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to draw a vertical line for a specific month date (period).

The expected graph is :
[image]

The dataframe I want to draw (named complete) look like that :

```
      ENTRETIEN FRAIS_FINANCIER
month       
2017-10 57.48   311.34
2017-11 0.00    0.00
2017-12 0.00    0.00
2018-01 0.00    0.00
2018-02 57.48   311.34
2018-03 57.48   311.34
2018-04 0.00    368.82
2018-05 0.00    368.82
2018-06 0.00    368.82
2018-07 0.00    368.82
2018-08 0.00    368.82
2018-09 0.00    368.82
2018-10 0.00    0.00
2018-11 0.00    368.82
2018-12 0.00    368.82
2019-01 57.48   311.34
2019-02 57.48   311.34
2019-03 57.48   311.34
2019-04 57.48   311.34
2019-05 0.00    368.82
2019-06 0.00    368.82
2019-07 0.00    368.82
2019-08 0.00    368.82
2019-09 0.00    368.82
2019-10 0.00    0.00
2019-11 0.00    368.82
```

Here is my code :

```
ax = complete.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
# Limite
plt.axvline(max(complete.index), color="red", linestyle="--", lw=2, label="Limite", ax=ax)
```

But with the code I have this error :

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'Period'
```

I can't figure out how to do it properly, can you help me ?

Comment: `plt.axvline(x=complete.index.size, ymin=0, ymax=complete.sum(axis=1).max(), color="red", linestyle="--", lw=2, label="Limite", ax=ax)`

Comment: Could you please provide sample data (data as an executable code snippet instead of an image)?

Comment: @Scotty1- Sorry, I edited my message

Comment: If I put your line, I get : 'Line2D' object has no property 'ax'. I tried removing all ax and I get the graph, with the legend having limit, but the line is not visible on graph ...

Comment: What you want to achieve is to draw a line horizontally, isn't that what you want to achieve? You can draw it with this. `ax.axhline(max(complete.index), color="red", linestyle="--", lw=2, label="Limite")`

Comment: @LCMa Thanks for the edit and no problem at all. :) Yep, forgot to remove the `ax` argument from your example.

Answer (score 3):

Plot the vertical line with:

```
ax = complete.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.axvline(
    x=complete.index.size - 1, ymin=0, ymax=complete.sum(axis=1).max(), 
    color="red", linestyle="--", lw=2, label="Limite"
)
```

Since barplot transforms the x-axis limits to numeric values increasing by 1 for each bar, the last bar has the "index" `complete.index.size - 1`. Thus this is the x-position for your vertical line.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! What I was missing was this barplot x-axis transformation

Comment: You are welcome! Yep, when plotting with pandas, this is done automatically, thus it is easy to oversee it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range('2017-10-01','2019-11-01', freq='1M')
val = np.random.randint(0,50,(25,))
val2 = np.random.randint(0,350,(25,))
complete = pd.DataFrame({'month':pd.to_datetime(date_rng, format='%Y-%m'), 'ENTRETIEN':val,'FRAIS_FINANCIER':val2})
ax = complete.plot(x='month', kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.axvline(max(complete.index), color="blue", linestyle="--", lw=2, label="Limite")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, but has I showed on my exemple graph : I try to do a vertical line

Comment: I switched to vertical lines.

Comment: But it still raises the same error as in the question. You forgot to set the months as index, thus you have a numeric index.